# object name with dot in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have some config file that I need to create, its a routers configuration file and I am trying to programmatically create the file. An excerpt of the file is like this.

```
link.b:{
  en:0x1f,
  an:0x1f,
  spdc:[0x0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],
  dpxc:0x1f,
  fct:0x0,
  fp1:0x3e,
  fp2:0x3d,
  fp3:0x3b,
  fp4:0x37,
  fp5:0x2f,
  fp6:0x1f,
  lck:0x0,
  lckf:0x0,
  imr:0x0,
  omr:0x0,
  mrto:0x1,
  vlan:[0x1,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01],
  vlnh:[0x0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],
  vlni:[0x0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],
  dvid:[0x1,0x000b,0x000b,0x000a,0x000b,0x0001],
  fvid:0x0,
  ir:[0x0,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000],
  or:[0x0,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000],
  srt:[0x0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],
  suni:0x0,
  poe:[0x1,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x00],
  prio:[0xff,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00],
  nm0:'506f727431',
  nm1:'506f727432',
  nm2:'506f727433',
  nm3:'343033',
  nm4:'343039'
},
```

So I need to somehow export `link.b` I can't create an object like that because I need to either nest `b` inside of `link` but then the output (expectedly) is

```
  link: {
    b: {
      en: 31,
      an: 63,
      spdc: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      dpxc: 63,
      fct: 63,
      fp1: 62,
      fp2: 61,
      fp3: 59,
      fp4: 55,
...
```

which is not valid for the router. and doing

```
'link.b' : {
      en: 31,
      an: 63,
      spdc: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
      dpxc: 63,
      fct: 63,
      fp1: 62,
      fp2: 61,
      fp3: 59,
      fp4: 55,
....
```

Is equally invalid for the router. So is there anyway I can output `link.b : {` **not** `'link.b' : {` and **not** `link : { b: {`

Comment: That's not a valid JavaScript/JSON object. Not sure if that's intentional (the router format expects it like this). However, have you tried generating a string instead of a JS object?

Comment: Ye, i'm aware its not valid, stuck with what i have to do. It's very close to an object so makes working with everything much neater. Guess it will have to be a string. thanks!